# R regular expression

Tags: regex, r, backslash

I have a string like below.

```
testSampe <- "Old:windows\r\nNew:linux\r\n"
```

I want to erase the string between `":"` an `"\"`.

Like this `"Old\r\nNew\r\n"`.

How can I construct the regex for this?

I tried to gsub function with regex `":.*\\\\"`, It doesn't work.

```
 gsub(":.*\\\\", "\\\\r", testSampe)
```

Comment: @nhahtdh, It returns `"Old"` unless `perl=TRUE` is given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> testSampe <- "Old:windows\r\nNew:linux\r\n"
> gsub(":[^\r\n]*", "", testSampe)
[1] "Old\r\nNew\r\n"
```

Comment: I think only the 2nd solution should be kept. `\S` will stop before a space (ASCII 32).

Comment: @nhahtdh, You're right. I removed the first one according to your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have a choice of a few different regular expressions that will match.  See falsetru's answer or use:

```
rx <- ":[[:alnum:]]*(?=\\r)"
```

As a more readable alternative to `gsub`, use `str_replace_all` in the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(testSampe, perl(rx), "")
```